# How to build a torrent cluster on a group of Amazon EC2 for transferring files between machines?

Tags: amazon-ec2, cluster-computing, bittorrent

I want to build a torrent server on a group of Amazon EC2 machines. This is for completely internal usage. Essentially, I want a fast way to propagate changes to large files that need to reside on multiple servers. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

This idea has been explored already, with the most prominent and mature implementation I'm aware of being Twitter's [Murder](https://github.com/lg/murder):

> Murder is a method of using Bittorrent to distribute files to a large
>   amount of servers within a production environment. This allows for
>   scaleable and fast deploys in environments of hundreds to tens of
>   thousands of servers where centralized distribution systems wouldn't
>   otherwise function. A "Murder" is normally used to refer to a flock of
>   crows, which in this case applies to a bunch of servers doing
>   something.

The Twitter engineering blog features a dedicated article introducing [Murder: Fast datacenter code deploys using BitTorrent](http://engineering.twitter.com/2010/07/murder-fast-datacenter-code-deploys.html), which also provides a video of a respective presentation/talk by Larry Gadea.